# Why does including several libraries throw Runtime Error(SIGILL)?

Tags: c++, exception, runtime-error

I was getting SIGILL Runtime Error on one of my codes.
But then i noticed that just changing the libraries used made it run normally.

Previous code(throws Runtime Error on C++14):

```
#pragma GCC target("avx2")
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <list>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
```

Modified version(Gave AC on C++14):

`#include<bits/stdc++.h>`

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Rest of the code was same in both cases.

Comment: please show a [mre] and don't include `<bits/stdc++.h>`

Comment: I submitted this for one of the problems on SPOJ: https://ideone.com/h1oSy6

Comment: Maybe you can find the error if remove all the competetive programming "shortcuts". Those nonsense-macros just make your program unreadable and harder to debug.

Comment: Please add a [mre] to the question itself not as a link to an external site

Comment: `#pragma GCC target("avx2")` is the most likely suspect if the processor doesn't support avx2